# What's the use of passing a container to priority_queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, containers, priority-queue

Every time you want to use a custom compare function for a priority_queue you have to pass it a container too. It seems to me, you should always pass a `vector<T>` to it. Now at first I thought this is some kind of redundancy, but it shouldn't be the case. What's the use of passing a container to a `priority_queue` and how can I make use of it?

Comment: I don't like your  `vector<T>`. I want to use my own `vector<T, MyAlloc<T>>`. Why do you want to disallow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply passing it the underlying container type which, by default, is `std::vector<T>`. If you want to retain the default behavior then you're correct in saying you can always pass `std::vector<T>`. You can also use `std::deque<T>`, or any custom container that exposes the following functions:

- empty()
- size()
- front()
- push_back()
- pop_back()

But why must you specify a container before you can specify a comparator? Well, it just has to do with how the parameters are defined. `container` and `compare` are both default parameters, and `container` just happens to come first. Because of the way C++ works, you just have to pass all the parameters leading up to `compare` before you can pass it, meaning you have to also pass `container`. AFAIK it has nothing to do with `compare` needing to know anything about `container`.

Comment: The reason is that the comparator used is the one that comes with the container -- there's no sense in keeping two comparators around and ignoring one of them.

Answer (score 6):

`std::priority_queue` is a container adaptor. It doesn't actually know how to store the elements you put in it; it delegates that to a real container such as `std::vector`. It's rare that you'll want to use something other than `std::vector` as the underlying container, but you could use `std::deque` if you want to.

`std::vector` is the default, but since this is the second template argument, if you want to use a non-default value for the third template argument, you're forced to specify the second one, just like with function arguments.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that priority queues are actually binary heaps, and the latter are usually implemented in a contiguous storage, such as an array or `std::vector`.